# How to change jars in SVN in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea

I deleted and added some jars in the *lib* folder of my project and then I committed changes. It seems to be all right at first sight:
But in the *Project Structure* there are shown old libraries:

[image]

[image]

How to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will notice that the JAR files which you deleted are now being shown in red.  If you hover over them IntelliJ should tell you that they are invalid references.  These old files will be ignored and should not affect the classpath within your project or your build.  If you want to remove them you can do so from the dialog.

Comment: But it seems also the project doesn't see new jars at all. The links that point the new jars are invalid.

Comment: Well are the paths valid?  Are there really JARs there?

Comment: Yes, I added jar to the folder on PC and to the project too.

Comment: If I remove and add jars in Project Structure, all works fine, but only locally. The SVN project doesn't change.

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere.  Removing a JAR from the IntelliJ project structure won't delete it from the file system.  However, you _should_ be able to delete and add to the file tree in your IDE.

Comment: So, is it possible at all to add and remove jars to/from SVN such a way that we won't have to change library dependencies in Project Structure after?

Comment: Not that I am aware.  Rather, you should explicitly be synching your IntelliJ project dependencies as you alter your included JARs.